# OpenGL,C++, Why is the glutReshapeFunc function giving a black opengl screen?

Tags: c++, linux, function, opengl, window-resize

I have been following an opengl tutorial, but for some reason when i added the reshape function(for window resize to fix ratio). the opengl window doesnt show the object(shape) at all, just a black screen.
i dont know if i made a misspelling or something.

Is the reshape function messing things up?

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

void renderScene(void);
void changeSize(int w, int h);

int main(int argc, char **argv){

// init GLUT and create window
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
glutInitWindowSize(320,320);
glutCreateWindow("Testing");

// register callbacks
glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);

// animation in reshaping
glutReshapeFunc(changeSize);

// enter GLUT event processing cycle
glutMainLoop();

return 1;
}

void renderScene(void){

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5,0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.5,0.0,0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0,0.5,0.0);
glEnd();

glutSwapBuffers();
}

void changeSize(int w, int h){

if (h==0)
    h = 1;
float ratio = 1.0*w/h;

// use the projection matrix
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

//reset matrix
glLoadIdentity();

// set the viewpoint to be the entire window
glViewport(0,0,w,h);

// set the correct perspective
gluPerspective(45, ratio, 1, 1000);

// get back to the modelview
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

Thanks for any help!
This is from the Lighthouse3d tutorials.

PS: if i take out the reshape function, the triangle shows up(works fine).

Comment: Are you by any chance rendering a black object onto a black framebuffer?

Comment: The reshape callback is triggered when a window is reshaped. A reshape callback is also triggered immediately before a window's first display callback after a window is created or whenever an overlay for the window is established. When a top-level window is reshaped, subwindows are not reshaped. It is up to the GLUT program to manage the size and positions of subwindows within a top-level window. Still, reshape callbacks will be triggered for subwindows when their size is changed using glutReshapeWindow.

Comment: pauluss86 its suppose to me a white object. thats what it is if i take the function out.

Comment: You might wanna note that if you were planning on doing more than putting a square on your screen you shouldn't touch functions like glBegin. Tutorials that mention these functions for anything other than "these functions are deprecated and should not be used" are outdated.

Comment: Cubic Where is a good tutorial with updated OpenGL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your triangle, as is, is not visible from that projection matrix you have defined with gluPerspective.

That matrix defines a view cone, pointing in the -z direction, with a near plane at z=-1 and far plane at z=-1000.

Your triangle lays on the z=0 plane, and as such is not visible.

You can either:

1. Move the triangle further back on the z direction (`glTranslate(0,0,-2)`, or move the vertices manually).
2. Use a view matrix that moves the camera away from (0,0,0), such as with `gluLookAt`
3. Use an orthographic projection matrix that includes the z=0 plane, such as `glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, you are either rendering a black triangle into your scene, its out of view (eg behind camera), or both.  To diagnose it, first try a lighting-agnostic method to render the triangle; add the statement `glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);` somewhere before the first `glVertex()` call. If you see a white triangle, problem solved.  If it's still black, put this before/after the above code:

```
glPushMatrix(); //save the modelview
glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-10); //move the rendering coords

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
  glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
  glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5,0.0);
  glVertex3f(0.5,0.0,0.0);
  glVertex3f(0.0,0.5,0.0);
glEnd();

glPopMatrix();//restore the view matrix to the original
```

If the `glTranslatef` doesn't work, try substituting different values into the xyz parameters (one at a tile, eg 0,-10,0). You may also try putting `glDrawBuffer(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK);` somewhere in your initialization routine as well, but this might be the default anyway.

**Edit**
I just noticed that the triangle lies on the origin (0,0,0) along the x-z plane, which is where the camera defaults to (hence it's 1 unit behind the near-clipping plane).  You'll definitely need to translate the triangle into view, or modify the modelview matrix to emulate the same (eg via lookAt; both methods are essentially the same). It is also possible that you are looking at the triangle edge-on which would make it invisible. In that case, insert a glRotatef(90,1,0,0); instruction *after* the glTranslate above to 'spin' the triangle to the correct angle.  Note that translate, scale, and rotate operate on the space itself, and not the objects within, ergo it all works backwards.  Normally, you'd scale an object first, then rotate it, then translate it to where ever.  In OpenGL, you translate the coords, rotate it, then scale.  GL then draws the object where it thinks '0,0,0' is, which is now at the modified position.